Retrieve data from Firebase realtime in ASP.NET MVC
I have an application with a Firebase database and I need to show data in a list as a web page using ASP.NET MVC. I searched about it and I didn't find any answer. I have data in Firebase realtime - data from my application, and I just want to show it in a list.
I tried this code, but the variable ends up being null.
public class DBController : Controller
{
    IFirebaseConfig config = new FireSharp.Config.FirebaseConfig
        {
            AuthSecret = "**************************",
            BasePath = "**************************"
        };
    IFirebaseClient client;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);
        FirebaseResponse respones = client.Get("User");
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(respones.Body);
        var list = new List<DataModel>();

        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(((JProperty)item).Value.ToString()));
        }

        return View(list);
    }    
}

And the view is just a list
